# What permissions are needed to run schtasks.exe on windows 2003 server

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2003, scheduled-tasks

The help file for schtasks.exe reads:

```
SCHTASKS /parameter [arguments]

Description:
    Enables an administrator to create, delete, query, change, run and
    end scheduled tasks on a local or remote system.
```

I'm creating a service account, on a windows server 2003 box, that schedules tasks and I don't want to add it to the Administrators group despite what the description above says.  Is this possible?

So far I have given the service account read and execute permissions on schtasks.exe, cmd.exe and the scheduled task that it will need to start and stop.  I can stop the task using the following:

```
SCHTASKS /END /TN "Name of Task"
```

But I get the following error when trying to run it again:

```
ERROR: Unable to start the task scheduler service.
```

I am having similar permissions issues with taskkill.exe